# Using SQL Server indexes to increase performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization

We are using SQL Server and SSMS 18.4.

We have a `TripAsset` table with these columns:

```
TripAssetID
TripID
Attachment1
Attachment2
Attachment3
```

We have a grid view which lists trips and data from the trip file. Each line in the grid must indicate the trip has Attachment1, Attachment2, Attachment3, etc.

The SQL to do this was joining on the `TripAsset` table and retrieving the entire attachment (which could be very large) just to indicate that the attachment exists. This was, obviously very slow.

A programmer suggested creating a separate file which includes `TripID`, `hasAttachment1`, `hasAttachment2`, `hasAttachment3`, etc. Then some process would keep this table in sync with the `TripAsset` table.

I think there has to be a better way, so I created the index `tripHasAttachment1` like this:

```
CREATE INDEX tripHasAttachment1
ON [dbo].[TripAsset] (TripID)
WHERE [TripAsset].[Attachment1] IS NOT NULL
```

Now I can run a query like below, where `tripID` is the trip for which I want to see if there is an attachment.

```
SELECT TripID 
FROM TripAsset WITH(INDEX(tripHasAttachment1)) 
WHERE TripID = [tripID]
```

This seems to run very quickly.

Is this the best way to attack this problem? Do I need the with clause?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Actually, the schema as shown here uses a "repeating group."  It has three fields to describe attachments ... no more and no less ... when actually this represents a *one-to-many relationship* that really should be represented by two tables:  `TripAsset` and `TripAsset_Attachment`.

Comment: I've never seen an index used like that before. Couldn't you just have a normal index on TripID and then put the 'where is not null' into the main query?

Comment: @Mike But in practice, there might be good reasons for not doing that.

Comment: I don't want to change the schema in the TripAsset table if at all possible. Might not be the best design now, but it is embedded into our system. I like Stu's answer below, which is that I think you mean by putting the "where is not null" into the main clause.

Comment: "A programmer suggested creating a separate file " - Fire for incompetence. One problem solved. There is no need for a separate FILE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to retrieve the attachment to check whether it is there:

```
Select
  TripAssetID,
  TripID,
  HasAttachment1 = Cast((Case When Attachment1 Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End) As Bit),
  HasAttachment2 = Cast((Case When Attachment2 Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End) As Bit),
  HasAttachment3 = Cast((Case When Attachment3 Is Null Then 0 Else 1 End) As Bit)
From
  TripAsset
```

Comment: Stu, I like this answer. We have several programmers who work on this project, and programmers come and go. Would you suggest putting this in a stored procedure and directing people to use the SP to check for existence of attachments, instead of hitting the file itself?

Comment: If your devs aren't necessarily strong in SQL, I'd suggest creating a VIEW and have everyone switch to using that (up to and including enforcing that by revoking rights to query the table directly).